# Youtube video on load through jQuery/JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

My goal is to display a Youtube video through a JavaScript function that will read the embedded code and load the video automatically in the div assigned. But I am not getting anything shown in the div assigned for the video. Is it because it has to be triggered by a button click?

```
<html>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var last_cnad_text_1 = '';
    var options_cnad_text_1 = {
    embedMethod:'fill',
    maxWidth:320,
    maxHeight: 320
    };
    function loadVideo()
    {
    val = $('#cnad_text_1').val();
    if ( val != '' && val != last_cnad_text_1 )
    {
    last_cnad_text_1 = val;
    $("#embed_cnad_text_1").oembed(val,options_cnad_text_1);
    }
    }
    $(function(){
    $('#cnad_text_1').keydown(loadVideo());
    $('#cnad_text_1').click(loadVideo());
    $('#cnad_text_1').change(loadVideo());
    }); 
</script>  
<body>       
    <input id="cnad_text_1" type="text" value="" size="60" name="cnad[text_1]">
    <div id="embed_cnad_text_1"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does it work if you just:  `loadVideo()` inside the document ready?  Without seeing all the code or demo (jsfiddle) it is hard to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

YouTube provides an autoplay option in the API:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#autoplay

Just set `autoplay=1` in your API request.

Here is a simple example that autoplays:
http://jsfiddle.net/tnuJt/